# To simplify the logarithmic expression and possibly find its inverse.

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms, inverse-function, hyperbolic-functions

While solving an equation, I came across an unexpectedly symmetric solution.

$$\frac{\log \left(\frac{a r+h}{\sqrt{(a r+h)^2-1}}+1\right)}{2 a}-\frac{\log \left(1-\frac{a r+h}{\sqrt{(a r+h)^2-1}}\right)}{2 a}$$

Now, I know that the 1st term of the expression corresponds to the hyperbolic cosine through the logarithmic transformation but the first term isn't so. Now, I want to ask if you know whether the 2nd term also transforms into something clever like that. Since I want to find the inverse of this solution, I think a short expression would make it beautiful to do so(?)

Thanks.

Comment: Both the answers below have more or less equal credibility and hence I am not choosing anyone of them as the "accepted" one.

Answer (score 2):

Using $x=ar+h$
$$y=\log \left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)-\log\left(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)$$ Make $x=\cosh(t)$
$$y=2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\cosh (t)}{\sqrt{\sinh ^2(t)}}\right)=2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)$$

To check it, using Taylor series, the first and last expressions give
$$y=-2i x\left(1+\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{3 x^4}{40}+O\left(x^6\right) \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

If we denote the numerator by $A$ and the denominator by $B > 0$, we have:
$\frac{1}{2a}(\log(\frac{A}{B} + 1) - \log(1 - \frac{A}{B})) = \frac{1}{2a}(\log(\frac{A + B}{B}) - \log(\frac{B - A}{B})) = \frac{1}{2a}(\log(A + B) - \log(B) - \log(B - A) + \log(B)) = \frac{1}{2a}\log(\frac{A + B}{B - A})$.
Now, you can simplify a bit :)

Edit: removed the conjugate quantity

Comment: if lets say, I call it some $m$ where, $$m = \frac{1}{2a}(log(\frac{A}{B} + 1) - log (1 - \frac{A}{B}))$$ then wouldn't squaring (as you have done on the last step) would include some "extraneous" solutions  as well? BTW, the solution which you have provided makes the RHS Equal to a definitely negative quantity inside logarithm and hence is essentially unusable.

Comment: I didn't square, I multiplied the numerator and denominator by the conjugate quantity $B + A$.

Comment: I see. But still, the second issue still holds perhaps this simplification is not feasible, I suppose?

Comment: OK, I see your point, $B^2 - A^2 = -1$, therefore the operand is negative. I'll edit my original post.